# Time Sheet Sum has incorrect values

Tags: arrays, time, sum, google-sheets-formula, duration

I have been facing an issue in the Time Sheet. where for each date i have calculated a total and then in the last accumulative total for all dates which is wrong.

For some employees the Subtotal is working fine but those whom are with most entries have incorrect SUM your help will be much appreciated on the problem.

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QC6g6SanRpJkm-bwwV6u60z3Z-GgUSjDZvWk5dDbHHw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXT(SUM(D8,G8,J8,M8,P8,S8,V8,Y8,AB8,AE8,AH8,AK8,AN8,AQ8,AT8,AW8,AZ8,BC8,BF8,BI8,BL8,BO8,BR8,BU8,BX8,CA8,CD8,CG8,CJ8,CM8,CP8), "[h]:mm")
```

try:

```
=TEXT(SUM(FILTER(D8:CP8, MOD(COLUMN(D8:CP8)-1, 3)=0)), "[h]:mm")
```

[image]